# Redefining the label used in captions

Tags: captions, naming

You can redefine your caption labels with e.g. [\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}](http://dcwww.camd.dtu.dk/~schiotz/comp/LatexTips/LatexTips.html#figlabel). Is there a way to do it just for certain figures/tables? I have an appendix and I would like to make figures/tables as Appendix #, and not Table/Figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put such a redefinition after the beginning of the appendix. You could even redefine within a figure or table environment to keep the redefinition local.

A cleaner way would be to define a new float type in your preamble. Besides the different names, you could have separate list of these floats: a list of tables, a list of figures and a list of appendices or the like.

For this purpose you could use either of these packages:

- [`trivfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/trivfloat) - easy to use
- [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) - more customizable, capable of preventing floating
- [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) - also with features to customize the float layout
- [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) - the very recommendable caption package with a lot of features concerning captions